# MySQL Multiusers with the same database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm creating a database structure for a pwa with HTML, Javascript and MySQL. I want to register multiple users in the same database but I really don't know how to do it for controll access to differents rows.

My actual database structure is: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7SY5.jpg)

What I need to do for show only the owner rows to multiple users?

**Option 1:** I need to create a token_id row to all tables with user's token?

Example:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPVA0.jpg)

**Option 2:** Or it's better to create multiples all tables for every user?

Example: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXM0J.jpg)

(*In this case I have two users with user1_token = 123 and user2_token = 456*)

*Sorry I can't upload images and I can't paste it with URL (error occurred)*

**Which of two options it's better? Or there are another solution with MySQL?**

*EDIT*
I don't know if people read this after edit, but I want to say one thing. After search alot I don't find anyway to implement a security method for read registers from a table without let hackers to access to other data.
I decided create few tables with name associated to user_id. Anyway there are tables that all people can access with permanent data.
Thanks for all.

Comment: Omg! Why people vote me down?

Comment: maybe they consider too generic, and not javascript related

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'm new here and sometimes it's hard understand all. Thanks for advice, I deleted some tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely option 1, add a user_id column to each table. You need to handle in your application code the user login, once the user is logged in, you filter only the data associated to the user. Presumably the user is able to view/edit only it's own data. User token might be something used in authentication/authorization but depending on your setup you might want to differentiate between used_id and user_token.

Comment: Ok, thank. But are there any problem with people who wants to access other users register modifying my queries? Or I can control it?

Comment: Becuase with MySQL there are any users management for controll accesss to certain rows in the same table? Or I need to do it programmantly?

Comment: For classic databases like mysql you need to do it programmatically in your app.  From mysql point of view you application can access all the data, you limit user access to data in your app.

Comment: This means that I can't control it all data access with my queries? What is a good alternative database where I can do that? I can use any of them, so I don't start the app yet.